# Jquery, check if charAt() is equal to a unicode character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, unicode

I've got a collapsible link which has the unicode arrow on it

```
►This is a collapsible link
```

And when someone clicks on it I want it to be turned into the down arrow ▼. However I am having trouble figuring out how to parse to replace this character.

Here is my code:

```
function CollapsibleContainerTitleClickApp(){
     $(".collapsibleContainerContent.app", $(this).parent()).slideToggle();
     alert($(this).text().trim().charAt(0));
     if ($(this).text.trim().charAt(0) == "\u25B8"{
        alert("inside the if statement");
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace("\u25B8", "\u25BE"));
     }else{
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace("\u25BE", "\u25B8"));
}
```

Now the first alert always pops up as the actual arrow (►) and viewing the source also has the actual arrow. How can I see if the first character is one arrow, and if so replace it with the other arrow? The second alert statement never fires so it's never passing the condition of the if.

Comment: Make sure you've got the right key code, as well - ► as you have in your question is `\u25ba`, `\u25b8` is the smaller arrow ▸.

Comment: In the future, keep an extra eye on JS syntax errors. You should have spotted this soon enough. In Firefox, hit `Ctrl+Shift+J` to see the JS error console. Or, better, install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have multiple errors in your `if` statement, this is why that branch is never hit.

```
if ($(this).text.trim().charAt(0) == "\u25B8"{
```

You forgot the closing `)` of the `if` statement.

Also, you're not invoking the `text()` method, you're trying to access it as a member, which it isn't.

Your code should look like this:

```
if ($(this).text().trim().charAt(0) == "\u25B8") {
```

Answer (score 2):

`charCodeAt(index)` returns the integer unicode value of the character at the specified index.  This is often the easiest way to test individual char values -- especially when they're non-printable, or special in some other way.  [(docs at w3schools)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charCodeAt.asp)

Also... be sure you're comparing the correct unicode values.  `"\u25B8"` is the "small right arrow" (`▸`) -- but the arrow you showed in your example is the "large right arrow", which is `"\u25BA"` (`►`)

so... a simple example using `charCodeAt()` *and* the correct unicode value:

```
var s = "►This is a collapsible link";
if(s.charCodeAt(0) === 0x25BA) {
   alert( "true!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this with css and jQuery, too:

CSS:

```
.collapsible_link:before { content: "\25BC"; }
.collapsed_link:before { content: "\25BA"; }
```

jQuery:

```
$('#link').click(function(o) {
   $(o).toggleClass('collapsible_link collapsed_link');
});
```